# AngularJS unable to POST headers

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, jersey

I am trying to make a POST request in AngularJ with a **password** Header,
I think the issue is with preflight handshake/CORS

I'm getting the following error -

[image: error]

Here is my AngularJS controller code -

[image]

and here's the request Header as per Google Chrome -

[image]

I am unable to figure out if the Header has been sent or not, as on the server side null value is getting received.

Comment: is CORS enabled in your server? It is the response that should have 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' - Refer (http://enable-cors.org/server.html)

Comment: yes everything is enabled from Server side, I am unable to send any  header, with the POST request.

Comment: _"yes everything is enabled from Server side"_ No, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the cors :

```
app.use(function(req, res,next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        next();
    });*/
```

Comment: where does this go? will it go in my app.js where I've written all my code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on **your php file** , that?:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST/GET');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

### UPDATE

As i read **your error message above** ,the error seems to be on the response, so i show you a screenshot of my request to the server(from my live web-app where i use CORS on the php), you need these headers on the response ,please see my response from the server:

[image]

Hope helps, good luck.

Comment: yes, all methods and everything is set to allowed on server side, I'm not sure if I am able to set the Header correctly? Have I used the correct syntax to set Header in my Angular POST request?